# What is this black symbol on a VFR chart?

Tags: faa-regulations, aeronautical-charts

What is this black symbol near KLBE VFR chart?
[image]

Comment: It, along with other symbology, is listed in the chart's legend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be the old Hi-Way drive in theater, given its placement near the highway and direction. It may no longer be such a good landmark as it closed in 2011, though the distinctive clearing is still visible. [image]

Answer (score 9):

[image]An obstacle, an "Outdoor theater".[https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/#sectional_radioaids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7SVy.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

An outdoor theater.  Used as a VFR waypoint.